# При импортировании модуля doctest выходит ошибка: LookupError: Could not find doctest (only use this function *inside* a doctest)

Tags: python, парсер, lxml

Пытаюсь освоить библиотеку lxml для парсинга сайтов. При импортировании модуля doctest(`import lxml.html.usedoctest`), у меня выходит ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/lxml-3.5.0-py3.5-linux-x86_64.egg/lxml/html/usedoctest.py", line 13, in <module>
    doctestcompare.temp_install(html=True, del_module=__name__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/lxml-3.5.0-py3.5-linux-x86_64.egg/lxml/doctestcompare.py", line 398, in temp_install
    frame = _find_doctest_frame()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/lxml-3.5.0-py3.5-linux-x86_64.egg/lxml/doctestcompare.py", line 489, in _find_doctest_frame
    "Could not find doctest (only use this function *inside* a doctest)")
LookupError: Could not find doctest (only use this function *inside* a doctest)
```

Может кто-то сталкивался с такой проблемой?

Запускаю вот этот код из мануала на официальном сайте:

```
    from lxml.html import builder as e
    from lxml.html import usedoctest
    html = e.HTML(
        e.HEAD(
                e.LINK(rel='stylesheet', href='style.css', type='text/css'),
                e.TITLE('lxml TEst')
            ),
            e.BODY(
                    e.H1(e.CLASS('heading'), 'Top news!'),
                    e.DIV('DIV',style='width:100px;height:100px;background:#ccc;')
    )
        )

    print(lxml.html.tostring(html))
```

Comment: А `from lxml import etree` работает?

Comment: @gil9red да, это работает

Comment: ну, тогда для парсинга вам хватит: `root = etree.XML("...")` или `root = etree.HTML("...")`

Comment: А зачем вам usedoctest? Он настолько не нужен для парсинга сайтов, что я даже не знаю что это, хотя юзаю lxml уже три года)

Comment: Приведите полный (но минимальный) пример кода, который к ошибке ведёт. На всякий случай: сообщение об ошибке говорит, что "эта функцию следует использовать только *внутри* `doctest`."

Comment: @andreymal я читаю на официальном сайте, и там в примерах он используется

Comment: Для ясности: минимальный и полный код, чтобы воспроизвести ошибку: `from lxml.html import usedoctest`.  Ещё раз: это *минимальный* код (одна строчка, один импорт), это *полный* код, который демонстрирует проблему. Всё остальное только отвлекает от вопроса. [mcve] Если проблемный  код из документации, то следует явно ссылку привести на конкретное место (в дополнение минимального поисков кода в вопросе). Если документация явно не говорит, что указанный код  внутри doctest расположен, то это ошибка в документации, которую можно на bug tracker опубликовать, чтобы документацию поправили.